# Weierstrass M Test and Analytic Functions

Tags: complex-analysis, functional-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, power-series

I have studied how to solve some PDEs using Fourier's Method. But, I'd like to know why don't we just use Taylor Series to solve these. After a little research, I found two interesting results: 1st) Uniform convergence Vs. Pointwise Convergence, which I understood fairly fine; 2nd) Cauchy-Kowaleski Theorem, which I could not.

My attempt to solve, generally, DEs (via Taylor Series) seems to be wrong according to the 1st topic. That's because I can only ensure pointwise convergence. Here's what I have been doing so far: I substitute every function into its Taylor Series form. Then, I conclude it will converge if:

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \left| \frac{f^{(n+1)}(z_0)}{f^{(n)}(z_0)} \right| \leq M \in \mathbb{R}_+\tag{1}\label{1}  $$

In order to achieve \eqref{1}, I rewrite $f$ into its Taylor Series form and then apply the ratio test. However, as it seems, it will ensure pointwise convergence which it's not sufficient.

So, my question is: **May we use Weierstrass M-Test to check whether or not the Taylor Series will converge uniformly? If so, how should I proceed with the computations?** Let's assume all functions $f$ are complex analytic in their open and simply connected domains.

How am I able to find every $M_n$ (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_M-test) ?

Any help and recommendations are welcome. Thanks

Comment: There is an easier Cauchy-Kowalevskaya theorem for ODEs. You can try that before the PDE version

Comment: @CalvinKhor thanks for your answer. Which one is this?

Comment: This one, http://www2.math.uu.se/~gaidash/1MA216/CK.pdf . I also just found this on a google, not sure if it is useful - https://arxiv.org/pdf/1912.03836.pdf

Comment: @CalvinKhor Thank you! I give it a try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I think you're missing is the definition of the radius of convergence.

1. A power series $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n z^n $ converges absolutely and pointwise for $|z|<R$, where $R$ is the radius of convergence, defined by
   $$ \frac1R \overset{\triangle}= \limsup_{n\to\infty} |a_n|^{1/n}.$$
   Indeed, for each $z$ such that $|z|<R$, we have $|z|/R<1$, so we can use the geometric series formula as follows:
   $$ \sum_{n=0}^\infty |a_n z^n| = \sum_{n=0}^\infty (|a_n|^{1/n} |z|)^n \le  \sum_{n=0}^\infty \left (\frac1R|z|\right)^n = \frac1{1-|z|/R} < \infty. $$
2. Once you know that it converges on some open ball $|z|<R$, you can check that  for each $\epsilon>0$, it converges uniformly on the set $\{z:|z|<R-\epsilon\}$. This is by the Weierstrass M test:
   $$ |a_n z^n| \le \left(\frac1R|z|\right)^n \le \left(\frac{R-\epsilon}R\right)^n =: M_n $$
   since $\sum_{n=0}^\infty M_n < \infty$ (again, geometric series), $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n z^n$ converges absolutely and uniformly.

Comment: Thanks again. But, may I generalize it to the following series, where that $f$ is any complex analytic function on open $R$? : $\sum a_n f_n(z)$

Comment: yes, as long as you can find the M_n. @Mr.N

Comment: I see, thanks again. Are the wiki's references satisfactory enough for self-studying? May I ask you any books/references on this?

Comment: It is quite likely that a good book on complex analysis will cover it, when they talk about Taylor series. Perhaps Rudin's RCA. IIRC i have seen people reccomend https://bookstore.ams.org/gsm-97/ @Mr.N

Comment: Thanks, again! I will get these books and read them.

Answer (score 4):

Power series don't converge uniformly on their disc of convergence. But they do so locally, meaning that they converge uniformly on every compact subset of their disc of convergence. The Weierstraß-M-test can be used to prove this.

First notice that every compact subset of a disc centered at $z_0$ is contained in a compact disc also centered at $z_0$. So it's sufficient to show uniform convergence on compact discs $K_r(z_0)$ with radius $r$ smaller than the radius of convergence $R$. On such a disc we have

$$\vert a_k(z-z_0)^k\vert=\vert a_k\vert\vert z-z_0\vert^k\leq\vert a_k\vert r^k,$$

and the series with these terms is known to converge because the original power series converges absolutely. Now we can apply the test to show uniform convergence on the compact disc. But it won't generally converge on the entire disc of convergence. For instance, the series expansion of the exponential function doesn't. Neither does the series expansion of $\frac{1}{1-x}$ at $0$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I understood that we can use Weierstrass M-test to check convergence. However, I would like to know how should I proceed with calculations. It seems I forgot to say that on the question. Let me edit it...

Comment: Which computations do you mean?

Comment: By computations I mean what Calvin did. How to find $M_n$.

Comment: They're right there in my answer: $M_k=\vert a_k\vert r^k$.

Comment: Oh, sorry. You are right. It's the same thing. So, basically, for $\sum a_n f_n(z)$, then  $M_n = |a_n| f_n(r)$? And how does the exponential expansion does not converge? Can't we make the radius $R$ from the example (wiki's page) $R \to \infty$? It seems we can't, since it must be bounded.

Comment: It doesn't work for arbitrary series, just power series (and probably other special kinds of series, but certainly not arbitrary ones). And the exponential power series does converge for all $z\in\mathbb C$. But it doesn't do so uniformly, because $\exp(z)-p(z)$ is unbounded for any polynomial $p$ (like the partial sums of the Taylor series), while this bound has to exist *and* go to $0$ for uniform convergence.

Comment: Thanks again. May I ask you any books/references about this? I'd like to learn more about this useful test and things related to it.

Comment: Sorry, I have no references for you, since I mostly learned complex analysis from lectures, not books.